Lebesgue equivalence class with no continuous representative
Usually, when working in Lebesgue theory, one identifies two functions $f$ and $g$ if their values only differ on a zero measure subset of the domain, or if $\|f-g\|_{L^p}=0$ for some suitable $p$.
Therefore, strictly speaking, elements of $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ are not funtions, but, rather, equivalence classes of functions.
Of course, given a representative $f$ of some equivalence class $[f]$, one could modify the valus $f$ attains on a zero measure set, and still get a representative of the same class $[f]$. This implies that each class admits a discontinuous representative, which brings me to the question.
Given an equivalence class $[f] \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, is there always a (necessarily unique) continuous representative $f$ of that class? Does the answer depend on $n$ or $p$?

No. Let $f$ be the characteristic function of the unit interval. If $g$ is another function which is equal to $f$ a.e., then $g$ is discontinuous at $0$ (and at $1$).
The reason is essentially that, if $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ has measure $0$, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is dense. In particular, there are sequences in $(-\infty,0)\setminus E$ and $(0,\infty)\setminus E$ converging to $0$ (from the left and right, respectively). On those sets, $g$ coincides with $f$, hence $g$ is discontinuous at $0$.
Variations of the same example work for every $n$ (and $p$, since our function is bounded and has compact support).

I guess the follow-up question would be, can we always get a function which is discontinous only on a zero measure set?

@Paulo: this is related to Lusin's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem

@PaŭloEbermann There's a subtlety, because it makes a difference whether we mean a) There is a set $S$, whose complement has measure zero, such that $f|_S$ is continuous on $S$ in its subspace topology, or b) The set of points where $f$ is discontinuous (on $\mathbb{R}$) has measure zero. Then (a) is true of all measurable functions, by Lusin's theorem, as mentioned by Qiaochu Yuan, while (b) holds iff $f$ is locally Riemann integrable, by the Lebesgue-Vitali criterion for Riemann integrability.
